# WCF POST - Returns Null

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, http-post, wcf-rest

I've been having some trouble with this project. I'm new to the WCF and web Service and I need to receive data through POST, and I got this little project where it has a POST function.

**IBookService.cs**

```
namespace SimpleRESTServiceCRUD
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBookService
    {
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, UriTemplate = "Books/")]
       List<Book> GetBookList();

       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Book/{id}")]
       Book GetBookById(string id);

       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "AddBook/{id}")]
       string AddBook(Book book, string id);

       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "UpdateBook/{id}")]
        string UpdateBook(Book book, string id);

       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "DeleteBook/{id}")]
       string DeleteBook(string id);

       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
             BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
            RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,                   
                    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                    UriTemplate = "SaveBook")]
        string SaveBook(String book);
      }
}
```

**BookService.svc.cs**

```
namespace SimpleRESTServiceCRUD
{
    public class BookService : IBookService
    {
        static IBookRepository repository = new BookRepository();
        public List<Book> GetBookList()
        {
              return repository.GetAllBooks();
        }    

        public Book GetBookById(string id)
        {
              return repository.GetBookById(int.Parse(id));
        }

        public string AddBook(Book book, string id)
        {
              Book newBook = repository.AddNewBook(book);
              return "id=" + newBook.BookId;
        }
        public string UpdateBook(Book book, string id)
        {
              bool updated = repository.UpdateABook(book);
              if (updated)
                    return "Book with id = " + id + " updated successfully";
             else
                   return "Unable to update book with id = " + id;
        }

        public string DeleteBook(string id)
        {
                  bool deleted = repository.DeleteABook(int.Parse(id));
                  if (deleted)
                        return "Book with id = " + id + " deleted successfully.";
                  else
                        return "Unable to delete book with id = " + id;
        }
        public string SaveBook(String book)
        {
            var a = book;
            // newBook = repository.AddNewBook(book);
            return "id=" + book.ToString();
        }
      }
}
```

I've been trying this with a Chrome Extension called Postman - REST Client and the var book always returns NULL. It never returns the value that I send through Postman.

I've been looking everywhere and I can't find a solution that suits me.

As I said, I lack knowledge on this topic so I would be glad if someone could help me with the problem or that could help me get an easier way/explanation of a WCF with POST.

Comment: you have actually built rest service using WCF. can you post client code? how are you calling this service?

Comment: I don't know what Postman is.  Use [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2) where you can see the request and response from the server.